# Container div changes width when a second row of floating children is added

Tags: html, css

In the following jsFiddle, the width of the container div is 100% when there is two rows, and less than 100% when there is only one (i.e. it wraps the children).

http://jsfiddle.net/fpooemgj/

I'd like for the container div `photo_stream_wrapper` to be as tight as possible around the children. How can I achieve that?

One row: [image: One row]

Two rows: [image: Two rows]

I want this instead of the last image. I want to eliminate the extra grey space: 
[image]

Comment: Do you always want the same number of items in each row?

Comment: Err well the problem is that the number of items per row changes depending on the size of the window.

Comment: Too bad, adding a _row_ div around the items worked. http://jsfiddle.net/fpooemgj/4/

Comment: If only it were that easy :)

Comment: if you want them in rows of three then just seperate them into divs of 3

Comment: Might want to look into flexbox.

Comment: Good idea, but sadly, I must support down to IE 8.

Comment: Phew! I'll keep you in my prayers, friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem, which can be referenced in my post:

[How can I make a container div the same width as it's floating children and center it when there are multiple rows of floating children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104640/how-can-i-make-a-container-div-the-same-width-as-its-floating-children-and-cent/39105231#39105231)

In my case I have something along the lines of this:

```
<div class="centered">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like jQuery is the answer. In order to "dynamically" set the width of the containing div, we need to calculate the width on a screen resize event via jQuery. We can use the width of the window and the width of the children to calculate the width of the inner container.

Here is the fiddle:

```
var resizeContainerDiv = function() {
  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  var childWidth = $(".child").outerWidth();
  var innerContainerWidth = Math.floor(screenWidth / childWidth) * childWidth;

  $('.container').css('width', innerContainerWidth);
}

$(window).on("load", resizeContainerDiv);

$(window).on("resize", resizeContainerDiv).resize();


.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}


<div class="centered">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/02arvnLx/1/

Comment: Even though I'm not too hot for JavaScript solutions in this case, it does work! Thanks for reviving this question!

Comment: I didn't want to have to use JavaScript for this either, but it was the only way I found to make it work. No problem!

Comment: Note that if you add true to .outerWidth(), the width includes the margin (e.g. .outerWidth(true)). By default, .outerWidth() only handles border and padding.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. You would certainly expect the floated container div to be no more than the width of the children (as it is with only one row).

If you know the number of items in each row, wrapping the items with a *row* div seems to work:

```
<div class="photo_stream_wrapper">
    <div>   <!-- "row" div -->
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
    <div>   <!-- "row" div -->
        <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer updated, though this does not work for OP because the number of items in a row is dynamic.